# Replace content of only one table with new version (should disable foreign keys?)

Tags: postgresql, backup, foreign-key, migration, pg-dump

1. I have 2 tables. 2nd has foreign keys to reference 1st.
2. I need to replace the whole content of the 1st table with the new version from another database. The new version satisfies all constraints and foreign keys.
3. I need a generic way to do it for any table so no exact name of foreign keys or constraints or columns may be "hardcoded" (but script "generation" like pg_dump does is ok).

I can't just truncate 1st table and insert everything from the new version: pg doesn't allow to delete referenced rows.

---

I tried to use deferred like this (I planned to automatically append it to pg_dump generated sql):

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

DELETE FROM X;

// ORIGINAL PART OF GENERATED SCRIPT
INSERT INTO X VALUES (10, ....)

COMMIT;
```

but I see `Key (id)=(10) is still referenced from table`.

The constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT second_fkey FOREIGN KEY (X) REFERENCES first (id) MATCH SIMPLE 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY
```

Comment: You can do the delete/insert in a single data-modifying CTE. Or declare the constraints as "deferred" then they are checked when you commit, not when you delete or insert

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, deferred doesn't work for foreign keys

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "delete/insert in a single data-modifying CTE" - how can I generate such script? pg_dump doesn't help much...

Comment: Of course deferred works for foreign keys - that's what they were made for. If you need to restore a **dump** using `pg_restore` then the only thing I can think of is to drop the foreign key constraint, delete the rows, restore the table from the dump, add the foreign key constraint again. The dropping of the foreign keys can be automated. You just need to generate a script first that re-creates them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've just read on dbo that "SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;" doesn't work for foreign keys even if they are deferrable.

Comment: Why not update the table (and some inserts)? Assuming that the unique columns are not modified, the FKs will not be an issue.

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ of course, but pg_dump doesn't generate such updates, right? and I need a generic way so I can't "hardcode" update statements myself.

Comment: Whoever told you that is wrong: [Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html) "*Currently, only UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, REFERENCES (foreign key), and EXCLUDE constraints are affected by this setting*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I checked and it tells me "Key (id)=(10) is still referenced from table" (CONSTRAINT second_fkey FOREIGN KEY (X) REFERENCES first (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY ) but the row with id=10 is inserted before commit so should work... (START TRANSACTION; SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED; ....)

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong: http://imgur.com/zJTnKgf  `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY` is invalid syntax (you need to specify `immediate` or `deferred`), so that can't be the statement you used to create the FK. Maybe your SQL client is still running in auto commit mode?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name uh, I thought I can just do "UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_constraint SET condeferrable = true;" but looks like that was my mistake.

Comment: No, it's not a good idea to update catalog tables directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deferred constraints solution (see an example in the question) actually works if I make the keys deferrable in normal way.

This didn't work because I did `UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_constraint SET condeferrable = true;` but forgot to set the same for `pg_catalog.pg_trigger`.

Comment: Big thanks to a-horse-with-no-name ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name )